# How to see all the columns in the Powershell in the Format-Table, regardless of the number of columns. (Missing columns)

Tags: powershell, formattable

How to see all the columns in the Powershell in the Format-Table, regardless of the number of columns?
Scrolling Horizontally would be more preferable to see all the missing columns.

This shows the names of the **all the columns**:

```
$rows = Get-NetUDPEndpoint; $rows[0].psobject.Properties.Name;
```

[All the columns in total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TuiF.png)

But, Here are many **missing columns**:

```
 Get-NetUDPEndpoint| select * | ft -Autosize
```

[Get-NetUDPEndpoint has more than 15 columns by default, but not all of them are shown in format-Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCOlu.png)

How can we show all the columns with Format-Table? All viable answers are appreciated

Comment: Use `Format-List` or not use any `Format-*` cmdlet at all and let the object be displayed as list ?

Comment: If you want to scroll horizontally you can use `Out-GridView`. `Get-NetUDPEndpoint| select * | Out-GridView`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I want the Table format as the output not the List.

Answer (score 1):

Note: If using a *GUI window* to display the table is acceptable, consider [Santiago Squarzon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) suggestion to use [`Out-GridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview), which does support horizontal scrolling:

```bash
# Shows table in a GUI window.
Get-NetUDPEndpoint| Select-Object * | Out-GridView
```

---

With the help of [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string) and its `-Width` parameter, you can make [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table) use the specified line width instead of the current console window's (buffer) width:

```bash
# Choose a high enough number to pass to -Width.
# Note: Typically doesn't render meaningfully *on screen* - see below.
Get-NetUDPEndpoint | Format-Table * | Out-String -Width 1024
```

- If you pipe the result to a *file* and view it in a text editor, you'll get the desired horizontal scrolling.
- However, **in the *console* (terminal), lines longer than the width of the console window (buffer) will *wrap***, hurting readability.

**Only *regular Windows console windows (`conhost.exe`)* offer a solution to that**: Set the window buffer width to the same width:

```bash
# Note: Works in regular console windows on Windows only.
& {
  param($width)
  [Console]::BufferWidth = $with
  Get-NetUDPEndpoint | Format-Table * | Out-String -Width $width
} 1024
```

Unfortunately, the above **does *not* work** in the following environments:

- In terminals on **Unix-like platforms**, there is no concept of a *buffer* width that can be larger than the *window* width, so trying to set a buffer width causes an exception, and line wrapping occurs for lines that exceed the window width.
- **Windows Terminal** does allow *setting* the buffer width, which can prevent wrapping, but then *doesn't support horizontal scrolling* - the lack of this feature is debated in [GitHub issue #1860](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/1860).